# Laravel development server cannot be accessed outside Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm trying to run a simple Laravel project inside a Vagrant (VirtualBox) VM. The guest is Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and the host is Windows 7 x64. I've set up port forwarding (`8000` on host to `8000` on guest), but when I run `php artisan serve`, though I get a message stating that the server is running on port `8000`, when I visit `localhost:8000` on my host machine, Chrome tells me 'this webpage is not available'. There are two complications:

First, if I use `curl` from inside the VM, I receive the correct page contents - so it appears the server is working fine.

Second, if I run a Python web server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on the same VM, I can access it fine on my host OS. Visiting `localhost:8000`, I see the directory contents listed. So it appears the port forwarding is working fine.

I tried deleting the `public/.htaccess` file in the Laravel project, to no avail. I'm no PHP expert, and this problem is hard to Google! Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Laravel Homestead? I find it's a much easier workflow when developing projects (not just Laravel).

Comment: The owner of the project hasn't been using it, so I tried to follow the steps they documented to set up the project locally. I've run across Homestead a lot, so I might end up having to go with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/581529/why-isnt-laravels-php-artisan-serve-server-being-accessible-from-the-www-on-ii) I tried

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

And it works fine now.

Comment: It didn't work for me still showing  This site can’t be reached

0.0.0.0 unexpectedly closed the connection.